# Ionic: How to override back button function?

Tags: ionic-framework

I need to override the back button function for both buttons:

- the back icon on top left corner of nav-bar
- the hardware back button (for example in android)

but only for one specific view, not globally. How can i do that?

Comment: The back button on the navigation bar should not exist when you are at the home view. so i did not need to override the back function of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is for android button, while the button on the navigation bar is a bit more simple:

Android button :

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
  if($state.current.name=="home"){
    alert("button back");
  }
}, 100);
```

Ionic button :

You can edit your topic and see how you have defined your menus and your views?

Comment: it is useful to note that this method returns "_A function that, when called, will deregister this backButtonAction._" For more info on cancelling custom back button behaviour, see this question: [Ionic cancel BACK button override](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32245181/ionic-cancel-back-button-override)

Comment: This is not working on IOS! And only works with hardware back buttons..

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to **override the back button functionality for both buttons** from within your controller. Here is the code for that:

```js
// run this function when either hard or soft back button is pressed
var doCustomBack = function() {
    console.log("custom BACK");
};

// override soft back
// framework calls $rootScope.$ionicGoBack when soft back button is pressed
var oldSoftBack = $rootScope.$ionicGoBack;
$rootScope.$ionicGoBack = function() {
    doCustomBack();
};
var deregisterSoftBack = function() {
    $rootScope.$ionicGoBack = oldSoftBack;
};

// override hard back
// registerBackButtonAction() returns a function which can be used to deregister it
var deregisterHardBack = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
    doCustomBack, 101
);

// cancel custom back behaviour
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    deregisterHardBack();
    deregisterSoftBack();
});
```

Make sure to inject `$rootScope` into the controller.

---

For more details and a proper explanation, see my full answer at related question:

- [Ionic override all BACK button behaviour for specific controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32246017/383414)