# Ionic onHardwareBackButton implementation

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm trying to control how the android hardware back button behaves in my app. I had it all working but now I can't reproduce it. The code I'm using is in app.js. I'm expecting the back button to do nothing but write to the console.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function() {
    console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
  });
```

Can any one see what the problem is? I'm running ionic CLI v1.7.11. I'm running the code with ionic view on android

Answer (score 1):

You can find full details, **including a full working solution for both hard & soft back buttons** at my related post:

- [Ionic override all BACK button behaviour for specific controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231737/ionic-override-all-back-button-behaviour-for-specific-controller)

---

To summarise how I handled the hardware back button, the trick is to *register an action for the Back button*, using code like this:

```
var doCustomBack= function() {
    // do something interesting here
};

// registerBackButtonAction() returns a function which can be used to deregister it
var deregisterHardBack= $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
    doCustomBack, 101
);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    deregisterHardBack();
});
```

The actual setting is done in that second block calling `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction()`.

This returns a method that can be called to deregister the action later on if you want to.

Answer (score -1):

It was a ionic view problem. Seems it does not support this.