# How to manipulate a back button to point to a previous-previous view?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

**Scenario:**
Index Resources > New Resource Form > Resource Detail

**Expectations:**
When I go from Index Resources to New Resource Form, the back button should go back to Index resources.
When I submit the New Resource Form, I should be taken to view the Resource Detail, the back button should go back to Index resources.

**Actual Result:**
When I hit the back button from Resource Detail, after the form has been submitted, it would take me back to the New Todo Form.

This is a copy of [How to manipulate a back button pointer to point to a previous-previous View](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-manipulate-a-back-button-pointer-to-point-to-a-previous-previous-view/2880), but it proposes a solution using `$ionicViewService`, but it has been deprecated for `$ionicHistory`.

How to do it using `$ionicHistory`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the back button in the 3rd page's controller and then use `$ionicHistory.goBack()` to navigate back 2 views down the stack.

```
// override default behaviour
$rootScope.$ionicGoBack = function() {
    // Default -1, -2 goes back 2 views
    $ionicHistory.goBack(-2); 
};
```

Of course make sure that `$ionicHistory` and `$rootScope` are injected into the controller.

Resources:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicHistory/
- [Ionic override all BACK button behaviour for specific controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231737/ionic-override-all-back-button-behaviour-for-specific-controller)