# Ionic cancel hard BACK button override

Tags: ionic-framework

There are questions about overriding the physical Android BACK button in Ionic, to provide custom behaviour:

- [Ionic override all BACK button behaviour for specific controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231737/ionic-override-all-back-button-behaviour-for-specific-controller)
- [Ionic: How to override back button function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585320/ionic-how-to-override-back-button-function)

But how do you **cancel the override** to restore default behaviour?

---

I have tried changing the priority of the handler, in the hope that a default handler may have a higher priority.

```js
var customBackButton = function() {
    console.log("this is custom behaviour");
};
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
    customBackButton, 101
);
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
        customBackButton, 0
    );
});
```

This does not work.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ionic v1 solution (out of date)**

---

According to the [Ionic docs for `$ionicPlatform`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/), the `registerBackButtonAction()` returns:

> A function that, when called, will deregister this backButtonAction.

This can be seen in the code for `registerBackButtonAction()`:

```js
  // return a function to de-register this back button action
  return function() {
    delete self.    [action.id];
  };
```

---

So the correct way to deregister / cancel the custom behaviour is to call that function when the controller is destroyed:

```js
var customBackButton = function() {
    console.log("this is custom behaviour");
};

// registerBackButtonAction() returns a function which can be used to deregister it
var deregisterBackButtonAction = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
    customBackButton, 101
);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    deregisterBackButtonAction();
});
```

---

A more complete example showing how to override & restore the hard and soft buttons can be found here:

- [Ionic override all BACK button behaviour for specific controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32246017/383414)

Comment: For completeness - http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/ - *Views can be cached, which means controllers normally only load once, which may affect your controller logic.* - deregistering on ```$ionicView.leave``` might be a better option than ```$destroy```

Comment: @Michal that looks like a much better option. Of course one would have to re-register it again at the appropriate event when the view comes back into ... err ... into view.

Comment: @Mohan - I don't work with ionic anymore. It would be great if you can write an updated v3 answer explaining how to do it these days. I will update my answer to reflect it is for v1.